# Getting Erros In Ruby on Rails (RAILS CONSOLE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Iam Just a beginner In Ruby And When I Try To Assign A variable a command this happens

This is The command I Tried Using IN rails Console

`lunch = Todo.new(name: "lunch", description: "iam going to cook lunch")`

basically trying to assign a table , column  some content

i get this error

`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'name' for Todo`

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Schema File =

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180818065237) do

create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.text   "description"
end

end
```

Comment: Look at your `db/schema.rb` file. Is there a `name` column in the `todos` table? I would guess there isn't

Comment: Can you share your `schema.rb` ?

Comment: If you don't have any data that matters, then you can do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna or, simply `rails db:setup`

Comment: I Have Posted Schema.rb

Comment: rails db:setup did Work Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake db:migrate`.  Your database is probably not current if an attribute isn't found.